# How to configure Tomcat7 server.xml Environment to take as value Network path?

Tags: tomcat7, network-drive, server.xml

I am trying to configure Tomcat7 serer.xml
the

```
<Host appBase="webapps/testweb" name="trythis.test.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context docBase="." path="" reloadable="false">
       <Environment name="WEB_APP_PROPERTIES" type="java.lang.String" value="\\10.120.13.200\config"/>
    </Context>
</Host>
```

Even though this config folder is accessible over the network my Tomcat can't access it:

[image]

Comment: Server configuration is off topic here and should be asked on serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: When I go there it says: Couldn't find serverfault.stackexchange.com
The Q&A site serverfault.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ I guess they changed their domain name.